Enfield Trip Report
I went to the TLG office in Enfield on Friday to report on our community and the support process for Recognized Lego Fan Media. I had a great trip, and it was wonderful to get to meet with folks from other Fan Media communities and connect with the Lego Community Engagement team members face to face.

Kim has posted a public report about the day that you can check out:
https://lan.lego.com/news/overview/community-manager-weekly-the-rlfm-meet-greet-day-in-enfield-ct-r81/
The trip included 10 minute presentations from 12 different RLFMs for the US marketing team, a tour of the Enfield campus, and some other unique opportunities.
I had a terrific time. Let me know if there's anything else that you'd like to know about the trip.
